# STM32 Timer triggers unwanted interrupts in encoder mode

Tags: timer, stm32, interrupt, keil, encoder

I'm using STM32f446RET6 and have configured TIM5 in encoder mode.I want the interrupt of TIM5 be triggered every time the period of timer overflows and goes to 0. Bellow is my code. When I watch the value of cnt in debug mode, I see that it goes up without any rotation of encoder. It seems the interrupt occurs all the time and without any overflow. How can I fix it?

```
void Hal_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef* htim)
{
 if (htim -> Instance == TIM5) cnt++;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could show us how you configure the timer?

Comment: If TIMx_CNT changes without input from encoder, it is not in encoder mode. Read out and check/post content of TIM registers.